TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier abc does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting
I'm getting the following error:
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Repo456 does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
Locally, no problem, things work fine.
What I've done so far:

Turned off Limit job authorization scope to current projects for non-release pipelines
Turned off Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines
Turned off Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines
Added ProjectA Build Service into Contributors and/or Readers of ProjectB
Added Agent Pool Service used by ProjectA into Contributors and/or Readers of ProjectB
I've set Default agent pool for the Pipeline's YAML > Pipeline > Build pipeline step to the Agent Pool Service used by ProjectA
I've checked the Pipeline's YAML > Get source > Checkout submodules option

What is there left to try?

My repo: https://dev.azure.com/Org/ProjectA/_git/Repo123
Module repo: https://dev.azure.com/Org/ProjectB/_git/Repo456

In my Project, I have the following .gitmodules:
[submodule "plugins/MyModule"]
    path = plugins/MyModule
    url = https://ORG@dev.azure.com/Org/ProjectB/_git/Repo456

Also tried:
[submodule "plugins/MyModule"]
    path = plugins/MyModule
    url = ../../ProjectA/Repo456

These steps were taken from:
Checkout submodule from different Azure DEvOps organization
and
TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier public does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting
Solution:
Ultimately, only need to add users under Repository (as opposed to Permissions), to have Limits for non-release pipelines set to Off and to turn off YAML protection.

Based on your description, I could reproduce the same error when using pipeline to checkout my Repo123 from ProjectA with its submodule Repo456 like below from ProjectB.
.gitmodules
[submodule "SubmoduleRepos/Repo456"]
path = SubmoduleRepos/Repo456
url = https://MyOrg@dev.azure.com/MyOrg/ProjectB/_git/Repo456


To fix this, we need to toggle off not only the option in ProjectA to Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines but also Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines.

Please also check the permission to Read the code from Repo456 is granted for pipeline build service accounts Project Collection Build Service (MyOrg) and ProjectA Build Service (MyOrg) in the settings of ProjectB.



Thanks for the nice write up! It seems that I needed to add the Project Collection Build Serivce.
